# Using Guice and Spring together in a web application.

Tags: java, spring, guice

How can I work with Spring and Guice beans in a single web application such that a Spring bean needs Guice to inject some dependency into it?

I am currently working on a task that involves migrating a standalone app to our companies in house framework. The in house framework uses Guice for dependency injection. The standalone app that needs to be migrated to this framework uses Spring and Spring - JMS. Also, the standlone app needs to be converted to a web app and deployed in an app/web server.

The catch here is that the standalone  app classes are Spring beans whereas the framework classes primarily contain a lot of Guice injections all over the framework.

Edit :
Based on the comments on this question, I have taken a look at SpringIntegration and I understand that I will need to bind all my Spring beans in a Guice module. I have the following questions :

1. Will all the Spring beans bound to Guice using SpringIntegration remain as singleton or will I need to explicitly define them as Singleton using @Singleton from Guice?
2. What would be the right place to create an injector out of my Guice module and thus initialize the Guice module? Note that my app is going to be a web app that does not use any web related stuff.

Comment: Guice has [Spring integration](https://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/spring/SpringIntegration.html). It's very easy to inject Spring managed objects into Guice created objects.

Comment: I took a look at Spring Integration and it makes sense. Although, my app is going to be deoloyed in a web container. Does this mean I don't use ContextLoaderListener in my web.xml and have Guice load my spring context files instead?

Comment: You need to supply Guice with the appropriate Spring context. Spring still handles managing its own beans and Guice proxies their injection into Guice managed objects. That being said - if your Spring beans use JSR-330 annotations then Guice should have no problem working with them directly...